# StackOverFlow error while trying to get coordinator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I get this error when I'm trying to get the coordinatess from GPS provider.

```
    package com.example.task1;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener 
{
    private Context Mycontext;

    boolean IsGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean IsNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean CanGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;

    private static final int MinDstance = 0; // minimum distance to change
                                                // update in meters
    private static final long MinTime = 0;// minimum time between update in
                                            // milisec

    protected LocationManager LocationMgr;

    public void GPSTracker1(Context context, TextView vieww) 
    {   
        this.Mycontext = context;
        GetLocation(vieww);
    }

    public Location GetLocation(TextView view) 
    {    
        try {
            LocationMgr = (LocationManager) Mycontext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            IsGPSEnabled = LocationMgr
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            IsNetworkEnabled = LocationMgr
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!IsGPSEnabled && !IsNetworkEnabled) {

                view.setText("No network availables");

            } else {
                this.CanGetLocation = true;

                if (IsNetworkEnabled) {
                    LocationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MinDstance,
                            MinTime, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (LocationMgr != null) {
                        location = LocationMgr
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinator();
                    }
                }

                if (IsGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        LocationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MinDstance,
                                MinTime, this);
                        Log.d("GPS enabled", "GPS Enalbed");

                        if (LocationMgr != null) {
                            location = LocationMgr
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinator();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
             * if(location != null) { Latitude = location.getLatitude();
             * Longitude = location.getLongitude();
             * 
             * 
             * }
             */

        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            Log.e("Error : Location",
                    "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);

        }

        return location;

    }

    public void updateGPSCoordinator() 
    {
        if (location != null) {
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() 
    {
        if (LocationMgr != null) {

            LocationMgr.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() 
    {

        if (location != null) {
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();

        }
        return Latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {

        if (location != null) {
            Longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return Longitude;
    }

    boolean canGetlocation() {
        return this.canGetlocation();

    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {

        AlertDialog.Builder AlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mycontext);

        AlertDialog.setTitle("GPS IS OFF");
        AlertDialog
                .setMessage("GPS Is Not enabled Do you want to go to settings");

        AlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        Mycontext.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and here is the Mainactivity code:

```
package com.example.task1;

public class Main_Page extends Activity {

    Button Run_btn;
    TextView View_txt;
    GPSTracker gps;

    ProgressBar pb;
    List<MyTasks> tasks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        View_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Long_lat_txt);
        Run_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Run_btn);

        tasks = new ArrayList();

        Run_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                gps = new GPSTracker();

                gps.GPSTracker1(Main_Page.this, View_txt);

                if (IsOnline()) {
                    RequestData();
                } else {

                    View_txt.setText("No network available");

                }

                if (gps.canGetlocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longtude = gps.getLongitude();

                    View_txt.setText("current location Is" + latitude + "  "
                            + longtude);

                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    protected void updatedisplay(String message) {
        View_txt.append(message + "\n");

    }

    private void RequestData() {
        MyTasks Task = new MyTasks();
        Task.execute("P 1 ", "P  2 ", "P  3 ");
    }

    protected boolean IsOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager ConMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo NetInfo = ConMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (NetInfo != null && NetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private class MyTasks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                publishProgress("Work With" + params[i]);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return "Task complete";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            updatedisplay(values[0]);

        }
    }

}
```

and here is the Log error:

```
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
12-07 11:18:37.581: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.example.task1.GPSTracker.canGetlocation(GPSTracker.java:179)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have infinite recursion here :

```
boolean canGetlocation() 
{
    return this.canGetlocation();   
}
```

change it to:

```
boolean canGetlocation() 
{
    return this.CanGetLocation; 
}
```

BTW, you should call your instance variable and the method `canGetLocation` to respect Java's naming conventions.

Comment: Many thanks but i want you to know i'm a beginner in android and I want to improve my skills  from the other  experience